# errors in Sending email in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I'm trying to create application that sends email 
I used classes like 
SKPSMTPMessage , NSStream+SKPSMTPExtensions, NSData+Base64Additions, HSK_CFUtilities, Base64Transcoder
 but it gives me the following errors

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKPSMTPMessage", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in MFViewController.o
"_kSKPSMTPPartContentTransferEncodingKey", referenced from:
  -[MFViewController sendMail:] in MFViewController.o
"_kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey", referenced from:
  -[MFViewController sendMail:] in MFViewController.o
"_kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey", referenced from:
  -[MFViewController sendMail:] in MFViewController.o
"_CFHostCreateWithName", referenced from:
  +[NSStream(SKPSMTPExtensions) getStreamsToHostNamed:port:inputStream:outputStream:] in    NSStream+SKPSMTPExtensions.o
  +[NSStream(SKPSMTPExtensions) getStreamsToHostNamed:port:inputStream:outputStream:] in  SKPSMTPMessage.o
"_CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToCFHost", referenced from:
  +[NSStream(SKPSMTPExtensions) getStreamsToHostNamed:port:inputStream:outputStream:] in NSStream+SKPSMTPExtensions.o
  +[NSStream(SKPSMTPExtensions) getStreamsToHostNamed:port:inputStream:outputStream:] in SKPSMTPMessage.o
 ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

keep in mind that I'm using Xcode 4.3 , 
what shall I do to solve this??

After adding the CFNetwork framework and SystemConfiguration framework ,
the number of errors decreased from 6 to 4 and it is now

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKPSMTPMessage", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in MFViewController.o
"_kSKPSMTPPartContentTransferEncodingKey", referenced from:
  -[MFViewController sendMail:] in MFViewController.o
"_kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey", referenced from:
  -[MFViewController sendMail:] in MFViewController.o
"_kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey", referenced from:
  -[MFViewController sendMail:] in MFViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Did you include .m files in your target?

Comment: can you tell me how to do this please, I'm new in iPhone

Comment: Is MFViewController a class created by you?

Comment: No, its the view controller that comes when creating the new app, but I added methods to send email

Answer (score 0):

This error message means that those classes search some objects in a framework that you haven't linked to your project. [Here](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development-advanced-discussion/14038-does-anyone-skpsmtpmessage-project.html) you can found what framework do you need: the CFNetwork framework.

### Edit

The other 4 errors might be caused by the incorrect importation of the SKPSMT classes. If that classes are downloaded as a library, you'll also need to link your app with that library.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I added CFNetwork & SystemConfiguration frameworks, the number of errors decreased from 6 to 4, look to the edit of my question

Comment: I will search about it but I'm not sure about why these error appears. In my opinion, it might need a library or another framework.

Comment: anyway , my target is to create app to send mail with custom view

Comment: Can you tell me if the SKPSMT classes are wrapped inside a static library (.a file)?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following linker flags:

```
OTHER_LDFLAGS = -lz -lxml2 -ltidy -ObjC
```